# What is the difference between ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} and . (relative directory)?

Tags: c++, cmake

I understand the difference between `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}` and `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`, but I don't understand what the difference is between the former and simply `.`?

For example, are there any scenarios where

```
target_include_directories(foo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

would behave differently than

```
target_include_directories(imgwarp PRIVATE .)
```

?

Comment: Some CMake commands accept (and correctly work) with **relative paths**. But almost all commands work with **absolute paths**. According to documentation, the command [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) accepts relative paths and interpret them relative to current source directory. So for that command `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` is equivalent to simple dot `.`. As for [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html), it allows relative paths only for `INSTALL_INTERFACE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple counterexample:
`add_custom_command` allows you to specify a custom `WORKING_DIRECTORY`. Passing relative filenames to such a command would be relative to the working directory. Explicitly making them absolute with `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` solves that.